# How do I scrape data from a page that loads specific data after the main page load?

Tags: ruby, screen-scraping, nokogiri, watir, watir-webdriver

I have been using Ruby and Nokogiri to pull data from a URL similar to this one from the hollister website: http://www.hollisterco.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/TrackDetail?storeId=10251&catalogId=10201&langId=-1&URL=TrackDetailView&orderNumber=1316358

My script looks like this right now:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.hollisterco.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/TrackDetail?storeId=10251&catalogId=10201&langId=-1&URL=TrackDetailView&orderNumber=1316358")) 

puts page.css("h3[data-property=GLB_ORDERNUMBERSYMBOL]")[0].text
```

My problem is that the Hollister page has some sort of asynchronous loading of data, such that when my script checks the area of the page with order specific data for a page element, it doesn't exist yet. I.E., the `<h3>` with `data-property=GBL_ORDERNUMBERSYMBOL` doesn't yet exist,  but in the browser if you let it load for another ten seconds, the DOM and HTML change to reflect the specific order details.

What is the best way to capture this data that loads after the fact? I have tried using the watir-webdriver, but not sure what I would need to do to make that one work either.

Comment: I think you mean AJAX for the async loading.

Comment: Make sure that you abide by their usage policy. That wasn't apparent to me because they had no robots.txt, but that doesn't mean you don't have to read their conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure how to do it with Open-URI, but if you want to use Watir-Webdriver, the following works.

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.new
b.goto('http://www.hollisterco.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/TrackDetail?storeId=10251&catalogId=10201&langId=-1&URL=TrackDetailView&orderNumber=1316358')
puts b.h3(:class, 'order-num').when_present.text
```

Note that a `when_present()` is performed on the h3 tag. What this means is that the script will wait for the h3 to appear before trying to get its text. If you know there are parts that take time to load, adding an explicit wait usually solves the problem.

Comment: Open::URI can only retrieve the original page, before the Ajax method fires. Watir-based gems are the best solution.

Comment: Awesome - thanks. That works well. One last question: Is there a way to make it so watir doesn't actually open a new browser? If I wanted to scrape multiple pages, I'm afraid this may take a long time... thoughts on how to accelerate things?

Comment: What do you mean by not opening a new browser? Do you mean you want everything to run in the background or you want to use an existing browser?

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a good way to run multiple threads - my issue is that opening the browser window, waiting for it find the data, then closing and opening a new browser takes time - is there a good way to run this faster in the background or with multiple threads at the same time?

Comment: You can use the same browser for all your work. You do not have to close and re-open a new one. Multi-threading should be possible, but you have to be careful about browsers sharing sessions. Your best option really depends on your context. I would suggest opening a new question and describing your scenario.

Answer (score 5):

Try installing [Capybara-webkit](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit) (make sure you have QtWebKit installed, otherwise the gem install would fail). This will give you a headless solution. Then try this:

```
require 'capybara-webkit'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = 'http://www.hollisterco.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/TrackDetail?storeId=10251&catalogId=10201&langId=-1&URL=TrackDetailView&orderNumber=1316358'
#change the capybara config to DSL and to use webkit
include Capybara::DSL
Capybara.current_driver = :webkit
visit(url)
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(body)
```

then parse the body as you would normally. To remove all that error messages try this:

```
Capybara.register_driver :webkit do |app|
  Capybara::Driver::Webkit.new(app, :stdout => nil)
end
```

Comment: where would you put the code at to remove the "error" messages? When I add it after `Capybara.current_driver = :webkit` I get the following when calling visit(url) ... `wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)`

Comment: As a heads up the qt install might take a while - in my case 2 hrs: https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/4166

Answer (score 0):

Following @benaneesh's answer I had to make slight modifications to get it to work in my ruby script and not show the unknown url messages...

```
require 'capybara-webkit'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

include Capybara::DSL
Capybara.current_driver = :webkit

Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|
  config.block_unknown_urls
  config.allow_url("*mysite.com")
end

#... rest of code
```