# Able to scrape some text from a website but not all the text, using Watir

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, watir

I'm able to scrape some text from the website, but I want to be able to gather the data about the coupons such as the title and the price.  https://www.krogerkrazy.com/coupons-com-printable-coupons-2/

I've tried seeing the text from all the divs, li, p, spans, using something like 
<% browser.divs.each do |x| %>  <%= x.text %> <% end %> but no information about the coupons comes up.  I've tried seeing the ps nested in the divs but nothing comes up for that either.

Controller

```
def save
    require 'watir'
    @browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, headless: true

    @browser.goto "https://www.krogerkrazy.com/coupons-com-printable-coupons-2/"
    sleep 10
    @divs = @browser.divs
    @spans = @browser.spans
    @body = @browser.body
    @p = @browser.ps
    @li = @browser.lis
end
```

View Page

```
<h1>Kroger Save Page..</h1>
<p> <%= @products.length %> products in Smith DB.</p>
<p> <%= @divs.length %> divs scraped. </p>
<p> <%= @spans.length %> spans products scraped. </p>
<p> <%= @body.text %> </p>
<p> <%= @p.length %> ps scraped.</p>
<p> <%= @li.length %> lis scraped.</p>
<p> <%= @li.first.divs.length %> divs nested in lis scraped.</p>
<p> <%= @li.first.ps.length %> ps nested in lis scraped.</p>
```

Comment: Is it possible those coupons are added to the DOM after the page loads with JavaScript? That could explain why you don’t see them.

Comment: That was one of my thoughts too, but I wouldn't know how to access the text if that was the case either.

Comment: Looks like that center module/section with the coupons is in an `<iframe>` (i.e. `<iframe id="ci_CouponsClickParentIframe" ...>`.  Try `puts @browser.iframe(id: "ci_CouponsClickParentIframe").text` to see the text in that frame.  For reference: http://watir.com/guides/frames/

Comment: Incredible, orde, that worked.  If you would like to make a post about it I would like to mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: @ChrisWilson: glad it worked for you.  The "iframe thing" is a very common gotcha, and this question is basically a dupe.  You can delete the question if you like, and that will help keep SO neat and tidy :)

Comment: SO won't let me because someone else posted an answer already.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

You should try seeing if it is present after the page loads. For this, you can use `when_present()`.

Docs are [here](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/EventuallyPresent#when_present-instance_method).

See this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11526164/10987825

Comment: for reference, watir-webdriver is deprecated, continue using the latest version of Watir. If you are taking action on an element you do not need to explicitly write a wait, it will be automatic. If you aren't taking an action, please use `wait_until(&:present?)` instead of `when_present`